Error by creating trigger function in Supabase
Problem Description:
I am working on an app where I am using AG-Grid tables and storing them in Supabase. The tables have columns and rows structured as follows:
Table: Stores information about the table itself (e.g., name, theme, etc.).
Column: Represents columns within each table, including field names and other properties.
Row: Stores actual row data in a JSONB format, where each field corresponds to a column in the table.
When a column is deleted, I want to ensure that the corresponding key (field name) is removed from all rows in the table, specifically from the data JSONB column in the row table.
The Structure:

Table:
{ "id": "uuid", "name": "Book table", "params": { "rowBorder": false, "accentColor": "#00569c", "borderColor": "#111112" }, "createdAt": "timestamp", "dimensions": { "width": 0, "height": 0 } }

Column
[ { "id": "int", "field": "name", "headerName": "Name", "type": "text", "createdAt": "timestamp", "tableId": "uuid" }, { "id": "int", "field": "genre", "headerName": "Genre", "type": "text", "createdAt": "timestamp", "tableId": "uuid" }, { "id": "int", "field": "wrong column for deletion", "headerName": "Wrong column for deletion", "type": "text", "createdAt": "timestamp", "tableId": "uuid" } ]

Row
{ "id": "int", "data": { "name": "It", "genre": "horror", "price": 20.00, "author": "Stephen King", "wrong column for deletion": "Need to be deleted!" }, "createdAt": "timestamp", "tableId": "uuid" }


Goal:
I want to create a trigger that runs before deleting a column. The trigger will remove the corresponding key from the data JSONB column in the row table for all rows that belong to the table from which the column is being deleted.
My database command:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_redundant_key_from_rows()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Remove the column key from the data in the row table
    UPDATE rows
    SET data = data - OLD.field
    WHERE tableId = OLD.tableId;

    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER before_column_delete
BEFORE DELETE ON columns
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION delete_redundant_key_from_rows();

Problem:
Error:
Issue
Function public.delete_redundant_key_from_rows has a role mutable search_path
Description
Detects functions where the search_path parameter is not set.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
